# Type of expression is ambiguous class error

Tags: swift

I am fairly new to the swift language I am just taking a course I bought and I found myself running into the same error code a lot. "Type is ambiguous without more context" and I understand what it means (i think), SO. I am trying to assign a variable that has a class stored inside to another parameter of a class if that makes any sense. I understand that I'm trying to assign a class to a string, but I guess my question is how can I make this work? is there a type I don't know about in swift that would allow me to do such a thing?

```
class Adress {
    let street: String
    let city: String
    let postalCode: String
    
    init(street: String, city: String, postalCode: String) {
        self.street = street
        self.city = city
        self.postalCode = postalCode
    }
}
class PurchaseOrder {
    var id: Int
    var shippingAdress: (String)
    var billingAdress: (String)
    
    init(id: Int, shippingAdress: String, billingAdress:String) {
        self.id = id
        self.shippingAdress = shippingAdress
        self.billingAdress = billingAdress
    }
}

var defaultAddress = Adress(street: "555 North Pole Ave.", city: "North Pole City", postalCode: "H0H 0H0")

var aliceGift = PurchaseOrder(id: 001, shippingAdress: defaultAddress, billingAdress: defaultAddress)

// THE ERROR IS HERE ^^^^^^.

aliceGift.shippingAdress = "1000 North Pole Blvd."
print(aliceGift.billingAdress)
print(aliceGift.shippingAdress)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a custom `Adress` class so you should use it in your code. Change `PurchaseOrder` to

```
class PurchaseOrder {
    var id: Int
    var shippingAdress: Adress
    var billingAdress: Adress

    init(id: Int, shippingAdress: Adress, billingAdress:Adress) {
        self.id = id
        self.shippingAdress = shippingAdress
        self.billingAdress = billingAdress
    }
}
```

Of course you need to change the rest of the code as well so you assign an `Adress` object and not a String if you want to change any adress property

Comment: you are my saving grace, you would not believe the amount of time i have spent trying to figure this one out lol. thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You've declared the types of `shippingAddress` and `billingAddress` incorrectly, as `String` instead of `Address`.

```
class Address {
    let street: String
    let city: String
    let postalCode: String

    init(street: String, city: String, postalCode: String) {
        self.street = street
        self.city = city
        self.postalCode = postalCode
    }
}

class PurchaseOrder {
    var id: Int
    var shippingAddress: Address
    var billingAddress: Address

    init(id: Int, shippingAddress: Address, billingAddress: Address) {
        self.id = id
        self.shippingAddress = shippingAddress
        self.billingAddress = billingAddress
    }
}

var defaultAddress = Address(street: "555 North Pole Ave.", city: "North Pole City", postalCode: "H0H 0H0")

var aliceGift = PurchaseOrder(id: 001, shippingAddress: defaultAddress, billingAddress: defaultAddress)
```